# How to pass liquibase properties to arg value of excuteCommand?

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

To execute a `shp2pgsql` command that needs a database port and an authentication (but doesn't handles a `-p password` option itself), I am doing this in local development mode:

```xml
<changeSet id="shp2pgsql_communes_2016" author="mlebihan" failOnError="false">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <not>
            <tableExists tableName="communes_2016" schemaName="public" />
        </not>
    </preConditions>
        
    <comment>Importation des shapefiles des contours des communes 2016</comment>
    
    <executeCommand executable="/bin/bash">
        <arg value="-c"/>
        <arg value="export PGPASSWORD=postgres;shp2pgsql -s 4326 -I /data/comptes-france/territoire/2016/communes.shp public.communes_2016 | psql -d comptesfrance -U postgres -h localhost -p 5434 -q"/>
    </executeCommand>
</changeSet>
```

You can see `export PGPASSWORD=postgres` and `-p 5434` hard coded. And I shall change this to allow deployments in others environments.

- the password will come from the *Liquibase* `password=postgres` property in my `application.properties` Spring-boot file.
- the database port, doesn't exist by itself as *Liquibase* property. I set it in `application.properties` too, as: `database.port=5434`, for example.

```
password=postgres
database.port=5434
```

But how, then, may I change my `<arg value="...">` parameter of `<executeCommand>` a way that they will receive these properties?

```xml
<executeCommand executable="/bin/bash">
    <arg value="-c"/>
    <arg value="export PGPASSWORD=$PASSWORD;shp2pgsql -s 4326 -I /data/comptes-france/territoire/2016/communes.shp public.communes_2016 | psql -d comptesfrance -U postgres -h localhost -p $DATABASE_PORT -q"/>
</executeCommand>
```

The message I'm receiving,

```
psql: error: invalid integer value "-q" for connection option "port"
```

looks like `DATABASE_PORT` isn't valued.